# How to check if there's a specific number of records for a unique_id in a df?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
data = {
    'ds': ['2024-02-01', '2024-01-01', '2023-12-01', '2024-02-01', '2023-12-01'],
    'y': [500, 600, 700, 800,500],
    'unique_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
}

input_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need a function to select the unique ids where the data is valid according to a minimum consecutive observations' parameter from last month backwards.

The expected output for a min_consecutive_observations == 2 is:

```
expected_output = {
    'ds': ['2024-02-01', '2024-01-01', '2023-12-01'],
    'y': [500, 600, 700],
    'unque_id': [1, 1, 1]
}
```

I'm having trouble coding a function that achieves this.

I got last month like this:

```
last_month_input = datetime.now().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
```

But can't wrap my head around how to check for continuity from the last_month_input backwards.

Comment: Firstly, do you know how to use `.groupby()`? If you do, please include that code.

Comment: What does "from last month backwards" mean? Like, does last month need to be included, or could it be any two months, e.g. January and December?

Comment: Regarding "can't wrap my head around", think about how you would write it out on paper. You've got step one, "get the first day of the last month", now go from there.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, convert to monthly period, use the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to determine if two months are consecutive (the reference is a [`MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html)) and count the size of consecutive stretches of months. If any is greater or equal than your threshold, keep the id:

```
# min consecutive observations
N = 2

df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])

def min_cons_obs(g, N):
    return (g.groupby(g[::-1].diff().ne(pd.offsets.MonthEnd()).cumsum())
            .size().ge(N).any()
            )

keep = (df['ds'].dt.to_period('M')
        .groupby(df['unique_id'])
        .agg(min_cons_obs, N=N)
        )

out = df[df['unique_id'].isin(keep.index[keep])]
```

Output:

```
          ds    y  unique_id
0 2024-02-01  500          1
1 2024-01-01  600          1
2 2023-12-01  700          1
```

Alternatively, compute the number of consecutive months per stretch, this could give you more flexibility to filter with a custom logic:

```
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])

def min_cons_obs(g):
    return (g.groupby(g[::-1].diff().ne(pd.offsets.MonthEnd()).cumsum())
            .transform('size')
            )

df['consecutive'] = (df['ds']
        .dt.to_period('M')
        .groupby(df['unique_id'])
        .transform(min_cons_obs)
        )
```

Output:

```
          ds    y  unique_id  consecutive
0 2024-02-01  500          1            3
1 2024-01-01  600          1            3
2 2023-12-01  700          1            3
3 2024-02-01  800          2            1
4 2023-12-01  500          2            1
```